# Azure DPS Delete Device Registration API error

Tags: azure-iot-dps

While Iam trying azure dps delete registrationid api iam getting 401 error. I have enable permissions(dps) in azure AD for the app for which used to get the token. But still getting 401 error. Can you help me if i am doing something wrong.

Thanks,
mbr[image: DPS error]

[image]

Comment: Did you fixed it, what was the reason..i have the same problem

Comment: I used nodejs sdk and able to delete using symmetric key/sas token

Comment: can you send how you create the sasToken i think this is the problem, how you create the sas token with dummy data and the method, please

Comment: pls check this..https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-control-access.. I was using this to deleting device registries in backend( azure webjobs) not at application side.

Comment: can you write me an email and to show you, liverpool_954@gmail.com